# How do I hide a mouse pointer in GNOME 3?

Tags: gnome, xorg, mouse

Some applications display their own mouse pointers but they fail to hide the GNOME mouse pointer correctly. I'm trying to find a workaround higher in the system (in GNOME or X). Any ideas?

What doesn't help:

- suggesting to fix the application in the first place
- disabling mouse with `xinput` - I obviously want to use the mouse
- using `unclutter` - doesn't work when I use the mouse
- switching `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.coursor` - plugin doesn't exist any more

I currently run Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.0 but the more generic solution, the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an alternative after six years.

Searching around the internet brought me to this AUR package: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xcursor-transparent-theme/

From there, the package build leads to sources over at http://downloads.yoctoproject.org/releases/matchbox/utils/xcursor-transparent-theme-0.1.1.tar.gz . This contains a completely transparent set of xcursors. After installing these with

```
./configure; make; make install
```

For Ubuntu 22.04, you may need to link the resulting folder to `/usr/share/icons/` with the following command

```
ln -s /usr/local/share/icons/xcursor-transparent /usr/share/icons/
```

The cursor became visible in my cursor theme selection in Gnome Tweaks.

From here, I can now change the cursor theme via the command line:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme xcursor-transparent
```

For reverting it, I can instead use `Pop` as the cursor theme, as I am on Pop OS. You'd likely use `DMZ-White` if you are on Ubuntu.

I used the keyboard shortcuts to bind <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to set the cursor theme to either one, effectively toggling the cursor on and off when required. From here, you could probably find out a way to have these commands run whenever you focus/unfocus the window that you want your mouse to be (in)visible on.

Comment: Marking as answer because it's more current - I didn't actually test it.

Comment: In my case, on ubuntu 22.04, after `sudo make install`, I need to create link at `/usr/share/icons/` with `sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/icons/xcursor-transparent /usr/share/icons/` before changing the `cursor-theme`

Answer (score 2):

Still happy to accept a better answer!

What happens to work for my current issue - which is `Unturned` (free game on `Steam`):

Create a file named `blank` containing cursor and mask data (white space matters):

```
#define blank_width 1
#define blank_height 1
#define blank_x_hot 0
#define blank_y_hot 0
static unsigned char blank_bits[] = { 
    0x00 };
```

Load it with:

```
xsetroot -cursor blank blank
```

When finished, you can load the default cursor with:

```
xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr
```

Comment: It isn't perfect by far. It just happens to work with `Unturned` in full screen but cursor still shows in other non-root windows (e.g. terminal, browser, etc. - it actually is perfect for this single case where I often do switch to these applications during gameplay but it's not good for more general purpose).

Comment: not working for me

Comment: Yeah, after 5 years it might. It's a low level solution that works directly with Xserver. Probably still doable on Wayland, try the man pages.