# How to hide the mouse cursor in Wayland?

Tags: wayland, cursor, kiosk

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 with Wayland for a kiosk system and need a way to hide the mouse cursor.

Most answers such as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/681269/how-do-i-hide-a-mouse-pointer-in-gnome-3) rely on x applications that won't work in Wayland so looking for a new solution.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu Frame, as suggested in a comment on your other question? if you are, there is a config option to hide mouse cursors, `cursor=null`, see https://mir-server.io/docs/ubuntu-frame-configuration-options

Comment: @Esther no I am just using Firefox in kiosk mode, Ubuntu Frame looks promising but [this user](https://askubuntu.com/q/1383691/512236) had stability issues with the browser so I haven't tried it yet

Answer (score 0):

You could [replace the theme pointer with a transparent pointer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/438275/62715). `xcursorgen` comes with the `x11-apps` package.

> First I generated X11 cursor file with xcursorgen from transparent png file and then replaced all X11 files in /usr/share/icons/Adwaita/cursors/

Alternatively you can [install a theme that has a transparent pointer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1357396/43087).